# Ubuntu 18 overheating after awakening from sleep mode

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, suspend, overheating

After resuming from Sleep mode my computer overheats after some time, and then shuts down. Problem wasn't solved after clean installation of Ubuntu/KDE Neon. Any suggestions?

P.S.: Hardware is AMD A4-3400 with Radeon HD

Comment: Possible off-topic question.   KDE Neon is not Ubuntu, nor an official flavor of Ubuntu thus off-topic on this site. Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I have this issue on Ubuntu and Neon both, so no off-topic

Comment: Check the running processes using `top` for high cpu usage

Comment: Open the laptop/desktop and blow out the dust/dirt. Worst case scenario is that the CPU thermal paste needs refresh.

Comment: 1) I checked -- nothing unusual; 2) If it was the case, when problem will not appear only after sleep mode, while PC works well after turning on.

Comment: Install 'lm-sensors' and use the command 'sensors' to check that the fan is operational after awaking from sleep.

Comment: It gave me this output:
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +12.2°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +75.0°C, hyst = +74.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        -58.0°C  (crit = +85.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +31.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)